# Drupal 8 Node edit form as block in page

Tags: block, panel, edit, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal 8, and I want to customize node edit page through the usage of Panels and blocks.
I'm searching for a module which will add node edit form into block selection, like [this one](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform_block), but for node edition and not node creation.

Is someone can help me please ?

Thanks,
Navalex